# Why is it OK it assume MSw (Mean Squared within) to be equal to ordinary average of cell variances?

Tags: anova, variance, mse

Statistic book (at least the one I'm using) say that MSw required for ANOVA (calculation of F score) will be equal to ordinary average of variance of each independent sample(cell) when all samples are of equal size.

For the following example matrix, the variances of sample a, b and c are respectively, 11.6, 11.9 and 27.76. So with this logic, the MSw will be average of these three values (i.e., ***17.087***). But if we calculate variance combining all raw values together (i.e., **d**= c(a,b,c)), the resulting variance values for sample **d** will be ***20.81***. This difference can become even larger depending on samples. Then why is it OK to assume that variance of **d** will be equivalent to ordinary average of variances of **a, b and c**

(**a** = 38, 35, 33, 33, 31, 28; **b** = 33, 32, 26, 34, 36, 34; **c** = 23, 26, 21, 34, 31, 32)